# Sound is not play when navigate through keys

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity3d and facing a problem. What I'm doing is there is a `Canvas` and canvas has two buttons up and down. I want to play a sound when the button is highlighted, I attached my script with both buttons, script works fine with the mouse. But I want to implement this mechanism with keyboard arrow keys, then I use a `Button Navigation System` and put the `up` button to `EventSystem` script as a first selected object. See image now button highlight, works fine with keyboard. But sound is not playing when navigate to `next` button through keys. How to fix this problem?

[image]

Code:

```
public class HighLightSound : MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler
{

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource Source;


    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        Source.Play();
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there an AudioListener in your scene? Does the AudioSource have an AudioClip to play? Is the event called when you have a breakpoint in the method and debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Unity Scripting API, you need to implement ISelectHandler and define OnSelect() method.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnSelect.html

Which in your case would give this:

```
public class HighLightSound : MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler,  ISelectHandler
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource Source;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        Source.Play();
    }

    public void OnSelect (BaseEventData eventData) 
    {
        Source.Play();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to implement [`ISelectHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ISelectHandler.html) as well:

```
public class HighLightSound : MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler, ISelectHandler
{

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource Source;


    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        Source.Play();
    }

    public void OnSelect(EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        Source.Play();
    }
}
```